# Android JSON variable Storing to Multi-dimensional array with keys

Tags: java, android

Code

```
    //Just assume this Json is perfectly fine.  Taken from a web services
    this.jsonData = [ { "mobile": "12345", "msg": "Test Message", "id": "28991", "name": "Test User", "senttime": "2019-07-05 14:36:24", "company": "My Company" }]

    public static HashMap<String, String> map_id_to_mobile = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, String> map_id_to_name = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, String> map_id_to_message = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, String> map_id_to_company = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(this.jsonData);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < JA.length()) {
        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
        map_id_to_mobile.put(JO.get("id").toString(), JO.get("mobile").toString() );
        map_id_to_name.put(JO.get("id").toString(), JO.get("name").toString() );
        map_id_to_message.put(JO.get("id").toString(), JO.get("msg").toString() );
        map_id_to_company.put(JO.get("id").toString(), JO.get("company").toString() );
    }
```

I am not satisfied with this code because of the the four different arrays.  I just wanted to use a php like multi-dimensional arrays where i could just do the following.

```
smsData[JO.get('id')] = array('mobile'=> JO.get('mobile).toString(), 'msg' => JO.get('msg').toString(), 'company' => JO.get('company').toString();
```

The reason for this is the ease of accessing the data when the array becomes more multi dimensional.  Any comments?  Any reference with similar idea pls let me know... been scouring stackoverflow but not satisfied with the answers...  Please help.

Comment: use bean class instead of hashmaps

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Can you post a dummy json like you want at the end?

Comment: This is how i want to get the values from the array.

| system.out (mydata[28991]['mobile']) //returns 12345 |
| system.out (mydata[28991]['name'])  //returns Test User |
| system.out (mydata[28991]['msg'])    //returns Test Message |

I hope my intention is clear enough.

Comment: hey, i posted an answer. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public  Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();


JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(this.jsonData);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < JA.length()) {
        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
        Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        innerMap.put("mobile", JO.get("mobile").toString());
        innerMap.put("msg", JO.get("msg").toString());
        innerMap.put("company", JO.get("company").toString());
        innerMap.put("name", JO.get("name").toString());

        map.put(JO.get("id").toString(), innerMap);
    }
```

Comment: map.put(JO.get("id").toString(), (HashMap<String, String>) innerMap);  Need to somehow cast the inner map, but can easily be fixed.  Thank you for this solution.  It works for me as of 25 July, 2019.

Comment: map.get("28991" ).get("mobile") //returns 12345 . | thanks my friend.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you solve problem maybe you can mark my answer as right :)